# save python list to text for next use

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm working on this project([Link](https://towardsdatascience.com/network-analysis-to-quickly-get-insight-into-an-academic-field-with-python-cd891717d547)) and I want to save export data in csv or text file for next use;
The code for Save data is

```
with open('listfile.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
    for listitem in record_list:
        filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
```

and the code for loadind data is

```
# define an empty list
places = []

# open file and read the content in a list
with open('listfile.txt', 'r') as filehandle:
    for line in filehandle:
        # remove linebreak which is the last character of the string
        currentPlace = line[:-1]

        # add item to the list
        places.append(currentP
```

but data not loading when loading data Properly

Comment: "not loading properly" is not an error description. How do you know its not loading properly? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Welcome to SO ;)
The code works perfectly for me :) Please add a more precise error description

Comment: Your code currently has some typos:
```py
places.append(currentP
```
with `python 3.9.7` I could have made it work with small fixes, please be sure that you've copied/pasted your code fully into this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can just use readlines() to load all of the data into a list which will keep every line as an element.

```
with open('listfile.txt', 'r') as filehandle:
    places = filehandle.readlines() # creating a list which makes each line an element
```